# Change values in rows

Tags: sql

I have the table `Table1` which looks like this:

```
ID  NAME
----------
1   TEST
2   TEST
3   TEST
4   TEST
5   TEST
```

I need a update to make an addition of text (1, 2, 3... n) at the column `Name`.

I need to look like that:

```
ID  NAME
----------
1   TEST1
2   TEST2
3   TEST3
4   TEST4
5   TEST5
```

Comment: Check out `UPDATE`, `CAST` and `||` or `concat`.

Comment: i need a single query... one single not more

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: And its an easy query and we are not here to do your work, so what have you tried?

Comment: Update Table1 set NAME=NAME + cast(1 as char(10)) where ID=1. but i need something that increments that 1 to... n value as id is changing

Answer (score 0):

You can just concatenate the id:

```
update t
    set name = concat(name, id);
```

Note:  some databases uses infix operators such as `+`, `||`, or `&` for string concatenation.

Comment: Doesn't look like he will be able to change concat to + or || him self

Comment: Sagi -nobody was born taught. 
But thank you for the time taken to read this

Comment: Gordon: 
Answer is yes ok , but I need not show ID but a stamps starting at 1 ... n values ​​that I want to change

Comment: @Geo . . . Your question suggests that what you want is the `id`.

Comment: @Geo, “I need not show ID but a stamps starting at 1 ... n values ​​that I want to change” — that should be part of the description because it's relevant to understanding what you are asking. You can edit your question to make it clearer.